# html anchor tag to load specific content in div

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an artist page and have a working script that loads content from other html files into a div in my index.html. This is the navigation structure that I want for the page. However, I would also like to be able to provide people with a url like [www.mywebsite.com/band](http://www.mywebsite.com/band) for people to go straight to the content of a specific project. How can I maintain the current navigation that I have, and still be able to give people links that load the index.html but with specific content loaded in the content div?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sadsappyabhi/pen/zYMxgXK

Site Repo: https://github.com/sadsappyabhi/abhiche

The navigation script:

```
 <script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#content').load('/home.html');

                    $('#navigation a').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var url = $(this).attr('href');
                        $('#content').load(url);
                    })
                })
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and hope all is well! It sounds like you are trying to build a Single Page Application (SPA) of sorts!

I think you can easily do what you are trying to do via:

```
<head> 
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#ID_OF_THE_DIV").load("THE_FILE.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body> 
<div id="ID_OF_THE_DIV"></div>
</body>
```

Another way would use http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js basically using a script tag to insert your html in a div:

```
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>
<div w3-include-html="THE_FILE.html"></div> 
<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
```

That being said, I think your attempt of doing this could possibly lead to issues around handling a lot of extra edge cases that may pose to be difficult. So, I highly advise using something like https://react.dev/ or something similar to handle your creation of your SPA website! It will make things easier and you can work on your javascript skills! For more information about SPAs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Hope this helps! Good luck!